# Is it possible to have the main callback functions in different files with love2d?

Tags: lua, love2d

Is it possible to have love.load(), love.draw() and love.update() in different files? and if so how would I go about doing that?

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT**

It seems I misunderstood your question; you are not asking how to switch between different callbacks, you want to have them in different files.

The principle is the same:

```
load_module = require "main_load"
love.load = load_module.load
```

---

I've written a scene manager to do just that. I will open source it some day but to give you an idea here's how it is used:

```
-- main.lua
function love.load()
  scene_manager.add(require "scenes/foo")
  scene_manager.add(require "scenes/bar")
  scene_manager.change("foo")
end
```

The `change` method looks like this:

```
  unload_scene()
  current_scene = scenes[scene_name]
  load_scene()
```

Basically you need to iterate over the various methods (`load`, `update` as well as `mousereleased` for instance) and then do `love[method_name] = nil`.

Then in `load_scene` you need to set it `love[method_name] = current_scene[method_name]`.

I know this is not a comprehensive answer but it should get you started. So, yes, it can be done.